# Maven : XML files are being skipped inside the target .

Tags: maven-2

```
 <profile>
         <id>tkweb</id>
         <properties>
            <file.name>ztweb-ws</file.name>
         </properties>
         <build>
            <finalName>${file.name}</finalName>
            <resources>
               <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/resources/ztweb/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                  <includes>
                     <include>*.xml</include>
                  </includes>
               </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                     <includes>
                        <include>**/Test.java</include>
                     </includes>
                  </configuration>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
      </profile>
```

Hi ,

This is my profile under the pom.xml file 
The folder resources / ztweb has got two xml files namely cxf-endpoints and services

please refer to the screen shot below of it

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ohn77n&s=7

But while building the target , why these two xml files are being skipped 
The result is this (Please refer to the screen shot of target directory structure )
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1znmrsy&s=7

Thank you for reading .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're overriding `build.finalName` to "ztweb-ws", the app isn't being built to `target/ztweb-ws-1.0`, which you showed in the screenshot. Look in `target/ztweb-ws` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by Look in  target/ztweb-ws ?? I have 5 modules ( a total of 6 pom.xml files ).

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say it. Your second screenshot shows a folder named `ztweb-ws-1.0`. Based on the pom snippet you showed, that's not the folder you're building to. The right folder is `ztweb-ws`. Since you only showed a small piece of a single pom, I can't speak to anything about your 6 poms overall.